# Misaligned active window capture in Remote Desktop

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, remote-desktop, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003

Recently I need to to do some reports by capturing the active window within Remote Desktop (mstsc.exe). The capture was done using Alt+PrintScreen but the resulting captured image is misaligned, 6 pixels from the right edge rolled to the left edge. A similar problem also occurs when using PrintScreen.

I'm running Remote Desktop on a Windows 7 machine. The problem occurs under Windows XP, Windows Server 2003 and Windows Server 2008 clients.

I could manually edit the capture, but there's at least 50 captures to do, so I would prefer a more straightforward approach.

You can see the effect in the capture below:

[image: Misaligned title bar of My Computer]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that it's caused by [ClipX](http://bluemars.org/clipx/), a clipboard history manager. If I turn off ClipX then it works as expected.